# Who gets the money from auctioning the North Pole?

Tags: jules-verne

(Asking in the same spirit as [a previous question I asked about Heinlein's *The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/157365/4918), only it's a lot more money this time.)

Jules Verne's novel *Sans dessus dessous* (English titles *The Purchase of the North Pole* or *Topsy-Turvy*) starts with an auction that sells a huge area of land near the North Pole.  That land has so far been unexplored and inaccessible, so also unclaimed by any country.  The United States of America buys the land for 814000 US dollars.  The Gun Club pays that money on behalf of the States, mostly from a donation by the rich widow Mrs Evangélina Scorbitt.

Who gets that money?  How is it used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that the land was essentially unclaimed (except by the poor schmoes who live there), a corporation called the *North Polar Practical Association* asked the US Government to host an auction to determine its ownership. As such, any monies raised would go to the US Government, minus a fee for the auction company (but see below).

> “It can thus be considered that the region extending from the eighty-fourth parallel to the Pole is still undivided among the different States of the globe. It is, therefore, excellently adapted for annexation as a private estate after formal purchase in public auction.
>
> **“The property belongs to nobody by right of occupation, and the Government of the United States of America, having been applied to in the matter, have undertaken to name an official auctioneer for the purposes of its disposal.**
>
> “A company has been formed at Baltimore, under the title of the North Polar Practical Association, which proposes to acquire the region by purchase, and thus obtain an indefeasible title to all the continents, islands, islets, rocks, seas, lakes, rivers, and watercourses whatsoever of which this Arctic territory is composed, although these may be now covered with ice, which ice may in summertime disappear.

The US is explicitly named as the nominator. We learn that a sizeable proportion of that money (and possibly all of it) will be used support the winner in their claim by settling any counter-claims from countries bordering the region.

> It may be that this communication will be considered as a madman’s freak; but at any rate it must be admitted that in its clearness and frankness it left nothing to be desired. The serious part of it was that **the Federal Government had undertaken to treat a sale by auction as a valid concession of these undiscovered territories.**
>
> ...
>
> The advertisement, it will have been noticed, assumed the principle that regions not known geographically and belonging to nobody in particular belonged to the world at large. That the majority of the Powers would admit this contention was supposable, but it was possible that States bordering on these Arctic regions, or considering the regions as the prolongation of their dominions towards the north, might claim a right of possession. And their pretensions would be all the more justified by the discoveries that had been made having been chiefly due to these regions; and of course **the Federal Government, as nominators of the auctioneer, would give these Powers an opportunity of claiming compensation, and satisfy the claim with the money realized by the sale.** At the same time, as the partisans of the North Polar Practical Association continually insisted, the property was uninhabited, and as no one occupied it, no one could oppose its being put up to auction.

So the answer is that **all of the countries mentioned in the earlier part of the story whose territories border onto the North pole (Great Britain, the United States, Denmark, Sweden, Norway, Holland, and Russia) plus countries whose explorers have visited the region (France, Germany, Austria-Hungary) would likely end up with a cut of the winnings.**